# Iterate efficiently over a list of strings to get matrix of pairwise WMD distances

Tags: python, matrix, nlp, word2vec, wmd

I am trying to generate a matrix of pairwise distances from a list strings (newspaper articles).

WMD distance is not implemented in scipy.spatial.distance.pdist so I hook this implementation: https://github.com/src-d/wmd-relax to SpaCy. However, I cannot figure out how to iterate over my list to generate the distance matrix.

Comment: Can you provide example with strings?

Comment: @Stormwalker: the strings are actual newspaper articles, which I convert into vectors using Spacy. I need to iterate over this list of vectors corresponding to the original articles and for each pair calculate the wmd. I simply don't know how to do this iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per doc:

```py
import spacy
import wmd
import numpy as np


nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
nlp.add_pipe(wmd.WMD.SpacySimilarityHook(nlp), last=True)

# given articles is a list of strings
docs = [nlp(article) for article in articles]

# matrix is just a list of lists in terms of Python objects
m = []
for doc1 in docs:
    row = []
    for doc2 in docs:
        # if distance is similarity function
        row.append(doc1.similarity(doc2))
    m.append(row)

result = np.matrix(m)
```

[Numpy matrix doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)